# C++ Code Creates CSV file, but does not write to it

Tags: c++, c++17, fstream, iostream

I am trying to learn how to write data to a file in C++, in this case a CSV file.  Currently my code will create the file in the location of my choice, but when I open the file, it is a blank document.  Any insight here would be much appreciated! Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


const char *path = "/Users/eitangerson/desktop/Finance/ex2.csv";
ofstream file(path);
//string filename = "ex2.csv";




int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    file.open(path,ios::out | ios::app);
    file <<"A ,"<<"B ,"<< "C"<<flush;
    file<< "A,B,C\n";
    file<<"1,2,3";
    file << "1,2,3.456\n";
    file.close();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to `file.flush()` your data in file before closing it, because it's written temporarily in memory, not on disk

Comment: Maybe the path is invalid or you don't have permission to write at that location.

Comment: @AlexLarionov It's supposed to flush automatically when closed.

Comment: OT: Avoid global variables. This is not a good habit to get into.

Comment: Hi @AlexLarionov, I added in 'file.flush()' directly before the 'file.close()' and it was still a no-go.  Was that what you meant?

Comment: Understood on the globals.  I just checked the permissions and switched folders to one I KNOW has write and read permissions just in case.  Still the same thing.  It will create the file but not write to it.

Comment: That's a slightly strange set of `openmode` flags.  Try `ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::app`.

Comment: It would be interesting to understand why exactly this failed. I mean if the path variable was in a different translation unit than the file I would say this was static initialization order fiasco however that does not appear to be what is presented. The accepted answer does not bother to explain the reason for failure. Maybe its the strange openmode flags like @PaulSanders mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by declaring file object instead of initializing it. Take a look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


const char* path = "ex2.csv";
ofstream file;

//string filename = "ex2.csv";


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    file.open(path, ios::in | ios::app);
    file << "A ," << "B ," << "C" << flush;
    file << "A,B,C\n";
    file << "1,2,3";
    file << "1,2,3.456\n";
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

So you're on the right path. I would also suggest that you don't use global variables. Other than that you should be good to go!

EDIT: I changed the path in my version so I can just word in the project folder.